# Magento 2 : Admin Sidebar links do not work

Tags: magento2, admin, dashboard, sidebar

After a migration of my site from one hosting service to another the sidebar links on the admin pages do not work.

The pointer hand appears when you hover over the link but the site doesn't react when you  click on any of the links ***'Dashboard, Stores, System etc'*.** The logo above each link doesn't display correctly too.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me
just try it.
go to `app/etc/di.xml`

find the line

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and Replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion which hasn't worked. The dashboard page doesn't fully load either unless you click on a link which is the main body of the page.

Comment: pub -> static and remove static folder and remove var/cache, var/composer_home, var/generation, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed

than run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: I didn't have var/generation directory but did the remove the other directories and run the static-content:deploy. The admin page now loads and the links are clickable but there is no graphics or styling on the page. It looks like a website where the CSS have been removed.

Comment: Also in php.ini change max_execution_time to 500, memory_limit to 2048M, post_max_size to 2048M, upload_max_filesize to 2048M and max_file_uploads to 2048 and check permission.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted customer services on my hosting provider who did the migration and they were happy to rectify this issue for me. Still not too sure what the issue was.